# Recoding sequence of values

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

Ciao,

Here is my replicating example.

```
have <- data.frame("STUDENT"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5),
                 "CLASS"=c(10,10,10,30,30,30,50,50,50,70,70,70,90,90,90),
                 "SCORE"=c(1:15))


want <- data.frame("STUDENT"=c(101,101,101,102,102,102,103,103,103,104,104,104,105,105,105),
                   "CLASS"=c(1,1,1,3,3,3,5,5,5,7,7,7,9,9,9),
                   "SCORE"=c(1:15))
```

So I want to basically generate a different order sequence of numbers for STUDENT and CLASS. In other words I want to recode STUDENT and CLASS so they are in a specific sequential order.

What I tried to do was

```
have %>% group_by(id) %>% 
            mutate(1=10,2=30)
```

but this is tedious and also does not work. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: `have %>% mutate(STUDENT = STUDENT + 100, CLASS = CLASS / 10)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
have %>% 
    mutate(STUDENT = factor(STUDENT, labels = 101:105),
           CLASS =  substr(CLASS, 1, 1))
```